# input element with attribute type equal to number in IE 11

Tags: html

I created the following test page with an input element

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<form>
<label>Numeric field:</label><br />
<input type = "number" min = "10" max = "100" value = "10" /><br />
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

However when I open this page in MS IE11 there is no any visible effect of the numeric stepper.
Is it a defect of IE 11 or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: According to caniuse (http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number), IE offers incomplete support for input type=number.  A jQuery polyfill may be useful; see https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill for more.

Comment: @Lance Leonard  Well, then write please an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to caniuse.com, IE offers [incomplete support for input type=number](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number). There's a [jQuery polyfill](https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill/) that may be useful, but you'll want to test it with your scenario.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

P.S. Converted comment to an answer, per OP.